# How can I stop json_encode() encoding twice?

Tags: php, pdo, json

```
$file_db = new PDO('sqlite:test.db');
if($file_db){
    $result = $file_db->query('SELECT id FROM sample');
    $encodable = array();
    while($obj = $result->fetch())
    {
        $encodable[] = $obj;
    }

    $encoded = json_encode($encodable);
    echo $encoded;
}else{
    die("unable to conenct to db");
}
```

I just want to output `{"id":"1"}` but it also gives me `"0":"1"`. Does anyone know why?

Result:

```
[{"id":"1","0":"1"},{"id":"2","0":"2"},{"id":"3","0":"3"},{"id":"4","0":"4"},{"id":"5","0":"5"},{"id":"6","0":"6"},{"id":"7","0":"7"},{"id":"8","0":"8"},{"id":"9","0":"9"},{"id":"10","0":"10"},{"id":"11","0":"11"},{"id":"12","0":"12"},{"id":"13","0":"13"},{"id":"14","0":"14"}]
```

Comment: Because you goofed on your database handling.

Comment: Have you checked the contents of `$obj`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is because of the way you are fetching the data with PDO. [`PDOStatement::fetch`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) enables you to choose if you want an associative array, an indexed array and more. The default is to have both. Change it to that to have the behaviour you are expecting:

`while($obj = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))`

Comment: In addition, why use `while($obj = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))` if you can use `$encodable = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`, there's literally no need for that `while` there.

Comment: I've read that using `fetchAll` is, in fact, slower than using the `while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))` loop. Can't find the source atm, though. The while allows you to double check the results, or process them immediately. So there is a point to fetch individual result sets

Answer (score 1):

$encodable returned from database contains both an index(number) and key(column name) for all values. So it is giving once for key and once for index.

You can iterate over the result and push the desired values into an array. Then encode it.

Answer (score 0):

try changing this line

```
while($obj = $result->fetch())
```

to

```
while($obj = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

from php documentation for fetch() constants
*Controls how the next row will be returned to the caller. This value must be one of the PDO::FETCH_* constants, defaulting to PDO::FETCH_BOTH.*

---

***PDO::FETCH_ASSOC:** returns an array indexed by column name as returned in your result set*